# how to request user permission to use scan nfc tag ios?

Tags: ios, tags, nfc

Please there is any way to request user permissions for my app to use scan nfc tag?
I cannot see a user interaction alert when start my app.

Comment: You do not need permission to scan an nfc tag. You simply start an nfc scan.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfctagreadersession/3281998-init

Answer (score 0):

Apple requires that you add the `NFCReaderUsageDescription` key in your `info.plist` file (details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nfcreaderusagedescription)) if your app uses the device's NFC hardware.

As part of the review process, you will also be required to submit a video of your app on a physical device interacting with an NFC tag.  From a recent interaction I had with Apple's App Review team:

> Before we can complete our review of your app, we need a video that demonstrates the current version in use on a physical iOS device.
>
> Specifically, we need a demo video that shows all the NFC functionality in your app, including your app interacting with NFC tags.
>
> The demo video should:
>
> - Show your app running on a physical iOS device, not on a simulator.
> - Clearly documents all relevant app features, services, and user permission requests.

Notably, the last bullet point implies that permission requests may be necessary... although they are not specifically called for in any documentation that I can find.  Apple does not make any permission requests when they use the onboard NFC, either (that I am aware of).

Apple's docs for adding NFC to your app are [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app).